# Type hint an instance of a metaclass

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I have a function which takes a class and returns an instance of that class. I'm trying to figure out how to typehint that, with a twist. Typically I would use the `typing` module and do something like

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound="BaseClass")

def foo(specific_type: Type[T]) -> T:
    ...
```

However, in my case I don't exactly want to take a class inheriting from a specific base class. What I really want to do is take a class *with a specific metaclass* and return an instance of that class, but I can't figure out a way to typehint that *without* adding some sort of dummy `BaseClass`. Ideally I would want the inverse of `Type`, something like:

```
M = TypeVar("M", bound="MyMetaclass")

def foo(specific_type: M) -> Instance[M]:  # <-- Instance generic is made up
    ...
```

This lets me specify that `foo` should take an instance of `MyMetaclass` (which a class with `metaclass=MyMetaclass` is) and return an instance of that instance (an object whose class has `metaclass=MyMetclass`).

**Is there anything in Python that lets me type hint something similar to the above?**

To be clear, there is actually a base class with `metaclass=MyMetaclass` which I expect `specific_type` should probably always inherit from. However, I cannot import it into the current context without creating circular dependencies; `MyMetaclass` is already imported into the current context. I *can* work around this (I'm not asking how to organize my project), but I specifically want to know if I can type hint an instance of a class with a known metaclass like this.